# No suitable URL request handler found?

Tags: server, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to connect to server on another computer in my network, I'm trying to send and check login data (username and password) with `fetch` to get json OK response. However, simulator is giving me error:

[image]

The code is this:

```
  LogIn() {
fetch('192.168.5.13:8087/login', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    config_name: 'default',
    username: this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password,
  })
})
```

I've been searching for a solution for a better part of the day, any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you've already tested the connection to your service through other means to confirm it's reachable via that address/port, you just need to add the correct protocol. Changing it to this (assuming it's not https) should do the trick.

`http://192.168.5.13:8087/login`

Comment: Thanks, thought that IP adresses wouldn't need that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using localhost, make sure you add HTTP:// at the start:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/yourRouteHere
```

As opposed to:

```
localhost:3000/api/yourRouteHere
```